# How to make multiple 'if' statements correctly (node.js)

Tags: javascript, node.js, steam

I have this try statement and I wanted to update it with more if's and make it to try 2 more times before finally declining the offer. I did not succeed. I have no idea how to do them correctly. Does anyone know how to fix my statement after?

STATEMENT BEFORE (WORKS)

```
try {
    offers.acceptOffer({tradeOfferId: offer.tradeofferid}, function(err, log) {
        if (err) { 
            helper.log('Error accepting trade offer ' + offer.tradeofferid, 891, err);
            offers.declineOffer({tradeOfferId: offer.tradeofferid}, function() {
                currentGameOffers.splice(currentGameOffers.indexOf(offer.tradeofferid), 1);
            }); 
            return;
        }
```

STATEMENT AFTER (DON'T WORK)

```
try {
    offers.acceptOffer({tradeOfferId: offer.tradeofferid}, function(err, log) {
        if (err) { 
            helper.log('Error accepting trade offer: 1st try' + offer.tradeofferid, 891, err);
            offers.acceptOffer({tradeOfferId: offer.tradeofferid}, function(err, log) {
                if (err) { 
                    helper.log('Error accepting trade offer: 2nd try ' + offer.tradeofferid, 891, err);
                    offers.acceptOffer({tradeOfferId: offer.tradeofferid}, function(err, log) {
                        if (err) { 
                            helper.log('Error accepting trade offer: 3rd try ' + offer.tradeofferid, 891, err);
                            offers.acceptOffer({tradeOfferId: offer.tradeofferid}, function(err, log) {
                                if (err) { 
                                    helper.log('Offer declined: failed 3 times ' + offer.tradeofferid, 891, err);
                                    offers.declineOffer({tradeOfferId: offer.tradeofferid}, function() {
                                        currentGameOffers.splice(currentGameOffers.indexOf(offer.tradeofferid), 1);
                                    });
                                    return;
        }
```

Comment: Use `promise` or `async`. This is callback hell!
https://www.npmjs.com/package/async

Comment: what part of your code "does not work"?  what are you expecting to see?  what actually happens?  are there any exceptions or errors in your console?

Comment: could you guys explain why is this wrong?

Comment: @DanO well theres basically first try to accept offer "offers.acceptOffer' and if theres error it logs and declines. I want it to try 2 more times.

Comment: @Petras - Are you sure all the `{` have matching `}` and I think there is even some missing `)` but it's **extremely** hard to tell the way this is written.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That code looks hard to read and maintain. It might work, but like you said, adding another few checks is a nightmare.

Take a look at the async library, namely [the retry function](http://caolan.github.io/async/docs.html#retry)

Now you code would look something like this:
(code untested)

`async.retry(3, function( retryCb, prevResult){
  offers.acceptOffer({tradeOfferId: offer.tradeofferid}, retryCb);
}, function(err, result) {
  if( err){
    //decline offer
  }
  // do something with the result
});`

Now it's easy to add more checks, change the delay, etc. Thanks for helping with control flow, async! : )